# Django i18n: makemessages only on site level possible?

Tags: django, internationalization

I have several strings in my site that don't belong to any app, for example

```
{% block title %}{% trans "Login" %}{% endblock %}
```

or a modified authentication form used to set the locale cookie

```
class AuthenticationFormWithLocaleOption(AuthenticationForm):
    locale = forms.ChoiceField(choices = settings.LANGUAGES,
                               required = False,
                               initial = preselectedLocale,
                               label = _("Locale/language"))
```

Now when I execute `django-admin.py makemessages --all -e .html,.template` in the site directory, it extracts the strings from *all* Python, .html and .template files, including those in my apps. That is because I develop my apps inside that directory:

```
Directory structure:

sitename
     myapp1
     myapp2
```

**Is there any way to extract all strings that are not in my apps?**

The only solution I found is to move the app directories outside the site directory structure, but I'm using bzr-externals (similar to git submodules or svn externals) so that doesn't make sense in my case.

Moving stuff that needs translation into a new app is also possible but I don't know if that is the only reasonable solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#localization-how-to-create-language-files) you could run `makemessages` from the app you like to translate, creating only the message files for that specific app. It is also possible to filter out some specific folders by using makemessages' `--ignore` argument. The results between those two would be quite different, though.

Comment: The `-i` (or `--ignore`) parameter actually does the job, good find! My batch file in the site directory is now `django-admin.py makemessages --all -e .html,.template -i myapp1\\* -i myapp2\\*`. Looking at your link to the documentation, I wonder why they don't mention that site-specific translations are even possible.

Comment: in ubuntu use: -i "myapp1/*.*" -i "myapp2/*.*" (by the way: this was usefull for me as well, I Am using buildout and there were a lot of packages in the eggs and parts folders that gave errors, excluding them, gave me just the needed translations for my app. So Thanx

Comment: About my remark above: I put my locale folder and executed the makemessage command in the wrong direction, I did it in the buildout-dir, and it should be done in the project-dir (there were the settings.py file is). So the ignoring won't be needed then. However, my remark about the format in ubuntu might be usefull.

Comment: What about reusable apps in your site-packages ?